How to get the abbreviated location code inside Azure ARM template
I'm trying to get the Azure resource's abbreviated location in the ARM template. I find a plenty of examples like the following to set the "location" parameter in the ARM template.
"location": {
   "type":"string",
   "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]"
}

But what I need is the abbreviated location code such as "wus2" for "WestUS2", "wcus" for "WestCentralUS", etc. I thought about using the if statement to set the abbreviated location as in "[if(equals(parameters('location'), "westus2", "wus2", if(equals(parameters('location'), "westcentralus", "wcus",...) as defined in the mapping table here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/how-to/automation-region-dns-records, but that seems like a lot of code for such a simple thing. Is there a simpler way to get the abbreviated location code inside an ARM template?


Abbreviated location code inside Azure ARM template

In ARM it won't directly supports this requirement like you do in bicep, Instead you can using if statement is the way to get this things done. But you consider not using for simpler form of ARM then you can this configuration,
main.json:
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "location": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "allowedValues": [
        "westus2",
        "westcentralus",
        "eastus",
        "eastus2"
      ]
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "locationAbbreviations": {
      "westus2": "wus2",
      "westcentralus": "wcus",
      "eastus": "eus",
      "eastus2": "eus2"
    }
  },
  "resources": [],
  "outputs": {
    "abbreviatedLocation": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[variables('locationAbbreviations')[parameters('location')]]"
    }
  }
}

deployment:
az deployment group create --resource-group vinay-rg --template-file main.json --parameters location="eastus"


Refer:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/variables
Template functions - logical - Azure Resource Manager | Microsoft Learn
